# How to change width of element that has Bootstrap styling applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have col-sm-4 Bootstrap classes applied to some list elements that are inside a jQuery slider (lightslider) component.

When the screen is between 801px and 991px, I want the list element to increase to 160px since currently, it is too small and the data is squashed a bit.

In Chrome developer tool, the styling is applied from the following css:

```
element.style {
    width: 142px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<ul id="responsive" >
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <li id="list-size-increase" class="col-sm-4 align-centre list-size-increase">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Products", "Home", new { id = item.Id, categoryName = item.Name })">

                <img src="@item.OutputImage" alt="@item.Image" />

                <div class="blend-box-top category-head" style="background: #0197BA url(@item.OutputImage) no-repeat 50% 0%;">
                    <div class="item-container">

                        <div class="desc-plus">
                            <p>@item.Name</p>
                            <p>+</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I've attempted with this id class, but I see no change:

```
@media (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 991){
   .list-size-increase{
        width:160px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that your style is being applied *after* any other styles which might interfere?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: can it be that the _width: 142px_ is an inline style? so that your media query is been overwritten?

Comment: I believe that in Chrome developer tool.. `element.style` means inline.  Which would explain this, because inline takes precedence over everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
@media (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 991px){
    .list-size-increase {
        width: 160px !important;
    }
}
```

> The `!important` keyword allows new styling to take precedence over inline styles. Oh how I love remembering and learning.